# How to make a proxy transparent to applications (Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

I have an Ubuntu server behind a proxy and several applications do not work because of it (e.g., apps that run on NodeJS). Is there a driver/application to make this proxy transparent to them?
Thanks